Diophantine equations - is my reasoning valid here?
I was thinking about the Diophantine equation $20x+24y=2024$ for a class today.
There is an obvious solution: $x=100,y=1$ but there are other solutions as well where $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers.
To find them, you can reason as follows:
$20 \times 100 +24 \times 1=2024$
$20\times 100-20\times 24 +20\times 24+24\times 1=2024$
$20\times76+21\times24=1$
So another solution is $x=76,y=21$
Repeating this process a few times, the following solutions are obtained:
$x=100,y=1$
$x=76,y=21$
$x=52,y=41$
$x=28,y=61$
$x=4,y=81$
I started wondering... *how many unique $(x,y)$ solutions are there to $Ax+By=100A+B$ where $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers.
Is it correct to say that the answer is simply the integer part of $\frac{100}{B}$? (is it correct to call that the ceiling?)

The first thing to do with $20x+24y=2024$ is to divide through by four. Makes life easier.

Thanks Gerry - doesn't work so well if A=20, B=27 though and I am looking to generalise this idea if possible.

True, but it helps you not miss lots of solutions, like $x=10$, $y=76$, and many others.

Yes... you have a point there. Well spotted.

Red, if you change $A,B$  you divide throughout by $g = \gcd(A,B)$

If
$ax+by=c$
then
$a(x-b)+b(y+a)=c$
so that,
for any $m \ge 0$,
$a(x-mb)+b(y+ma)=c$
and
$a(x+mb)+b(y-ma)=c$.
So you can go up or down
as long as the terms
in parens are non-negative.
You can get an expression for this
involving the
floor function.

And if $\gcd(a,b)>1$, then you can do even better.
